# WinForm and WPF Form rendering

Tags: wpf, winforms

Pardon me, if it is a silly question.
Can you anyone tell me how the WinForms are rendered (the background mechanism)
Also how is WPF Form are rendered. 
In simple, i want to know the rendering mechanism of WinForms and WPF Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF there is the [WPF Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) or [WPF Rendering Steps](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/03/wpf-rendering-steps.html) which states

1. Render all children.
2. Process OpacityMask.
3. Process Opacity
4. BitmapEffect
5. Clip geometry
6. GuidelineSet
7. Transforms

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Forms** renders its Forms using **GDI+**, while **WPF** renders its Windows using **DirectX**.